# How dopant enhances the superconductivity of BSCCO

Tags: electrical-resistance, superconductivity

i really need your help, I want to know the effect  of Dopant (for Example Manganese) in BSCCO (for example Bi-2212) in Resistivity? i read some articles saying it increases the critical temperature of the superconductor, But it didn't explain why,  and how  is that related to the resistivity when you increase the dopant content? Thank you!